# how to create a gwt mobile project with eclipse?

Tags: gwt, mobile

does somebody know how to create a gwt-mobile project with eclipse?
i would like to program a mobile web app with  [gwt-mobile](http://demo.gwtmobile.com/) and maybe a little bit later with the [gwt next interface framework](http://nextinterfaces.com/b/). i have never made a mobile web app and i dont know how to do it. there is no tutorial how to install everything or rather how to create a mobile web project with gwt mobile on eclipse. i would like to start with coding but i dont know how to install everything. 
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its Very Simple,**

Just Download the JAR File from here,

https://github.com/dennisjzh/GwtMobile/downloads

1. Create a new GWT Project.
2. Add this Jar to the Project Build path.
3. Start Working with the Library

I hope you know how to develop an app when you have a JAR Library available....